# How to programmatically overwrite DCI 2.0 policy via REXX or JCL?

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl, rexx, dci

as the title states we run DCI 2.0 on our mainframes to control MSU min and max capacity for our LPARs. I would like to write an automation that increases the maximum MSU for certain LPARs based on certain conditions, so simply creating a new policy won't do (as far as I'm aware?). I can't find any information how to do that via a program (preferrably REXX or JCL) and I'm very new to the whole mainframe world, so I probably missed something...

I'd probably just need to know how to do the equivalent of what we do in zDC panel when we overwrite with the line command 'o'.

If anyone has any pointers on where to look or even solutions on how to do this I'd greatly appreciate it. Since I'm so new I probably missed some important information in the question, I'm sorry if that is the case and feel free to ask or shun me for it, lol.

I've tried finding information on it here and through various google searches:
https://techdocs.broadcom.com/content/dam/broadcom/techdocs/us/en/pdf/ca-mainframe-software/intelligent-operations/ca-dynamic-capacity-intelligence/baseline-20/ca-dynamic-capacity-intelligence-2-0.pdf

Relevant information is at page 155, but that's only for the zDC panel.

Edit:
I'm not a smart man. I just read a bit through the linked manual and it seems that the CONTROLR commands (specifically /f CONTROLR,POLICY,O,...) are what I was looking for. I'll see how to use them in REXX or JCL, but I think I'll figure that out by asking around at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how to embed console command in REXX scripts:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=activities-using-console-host-command-environment

You can also process messages from the REXX script in the case that the commands have a response.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a smart man. I just read a bit through the linked manual and it seems that the CONTROLR commands (specifically /f CONTROLR,POLICY,O,...) are what I was looking for. I'll see how to use them in REXX or JCL, but I think I'll figure that out by asking around at work.